# PayPal sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to install PayPal on my localhost but whe i test payment.php get the following Warning in this file:

> Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable in 
>       /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/functions/PayPal/vendor/paypal/
>       rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalModel.php on line 176

**payment.php** codes here:

```
<?php   
$client_ID =  '********';
$client_Secret = '********';
require __DIR__ . '/PayPal/vendor/autoload.php'; 

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
            $client_ID,     // ClientID
            $client_Secret      // ClientSecret
        )
);

$apiContext->setConfig([
 'mode'=>'sandbox',
 'http.ConnectionTimeOut'=>30,
 'log.LogEnabled'=>false,
 'log.FileName'=>'',
 'log.LogLevel'=>'FINE',
 'validation.level'=>'log'
]);
//$total = $amount;
// After Step 2
$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setTotal('1.00');
$amount->setCurrency('USD');

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);

$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("https://example.com/your_redirect_url.html")
    ->setCancelUrl("https://example.com/your_cancel_url.html");

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
try {
           $payment->create($apiContext);
           echo $payment;

           echo "\n\nRedirect user to approval_url: " . $payment->getApprovalLink() . "\n";


} catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    // This will print the detailed information on the exception.
    //REALLY HELPFUL FOR DEBUGGING
    echo $ex->getData();
}

?>
```

I have to try to use this page for https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call

but i get sizeof() warning.

How can i solve this problem anyone can help me please ?

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/1014

Comment: What version are you using? They released a fix to support PHP 7.2+ compatibility. If you're using PHP 7.2 ensure you have the **newest** version of the library in your composer. [Here is the fix](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/commit/1df6286dc95039e1e2a41cd24ddcfe492ac20544) if you want to manually do it yourself, alternatively.

Comment: @MacBooc Thank you so much for your help Dear. It saved me.

Answer (score 8):

I have faced this problem, And I got my solution by the following change.

**File: vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalModel.php**

Change

```
} else if (sizeof($v) <= 0 && is_array($v) ) {
```

to

```
} else if (is_array($v) && sizeof($v) <= 0) {
```

Comment: `else if` as two words is a violation of PHP's PSR-12 guidelines; it should be written as one word `elseif`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as an alternative to updating the library or downgrading PHP.

Comment: how You change a vendor file !!! it is not recommended !